# Emulate graphic card Windows Azure VM, is it possible?

Tags: azure, 3d, virtual-machine

I have some virtual machines at Windows Azure and I need to run some games in these machines, but I'm not able to do that because of the graphic cards of the VM's, mostly games don't work with a generic hyper-v graphic card (like Far Cry 3). So, what I want to know: is it possible to do something to run these games on these VM's? like emulate a graphic card. Even if the game run slowly it will help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would require the VM to have a GPU. check out N-series VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json#performance-considerations